# Ember Computed properties and Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my Ember Controller, I have 2 computed properties (CP) as below;

```
itemsWithData: function() {
    var dataItems = [];

    return dataItems;
}.property('containsFailure'),
someArray: function() {
    var items = this.get('itemsWithData');
    var someArray = [];

    return someArray;
}.property('itemsWithData')
```

Now in my Ember Handlerbars template, while I only use someArray CP to iterate on and display values, I am not using the other CP (i.e. itemsWithData)

But if I do not refer itemsWithData in my template, the same is not getting executed in my controller (so even someArray does not execute since it depends on itemsWithData)

It only executes if I explictly add a dummy reference as below;

```
{{#each itemsWithData as |data|}}
{{/each}}
```

Is that how CP works in controllers/templates ? I need a way such that I do not have to add this dummy code in my template.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are observing an array, it should be `property('itemsWithData.[]')`.  `'[]'` observes the array for any changes in its set of objects (ie, adding and removing objects), but will not trigger if attributes on those objects changed.  See the docs [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html).

If you wanted to observe a specific attribute of each element in the array, it would be `property('itemsWithData.@each.name')`, which observes the set of names of each element in `itemsWithData`.  It will also trigger if an element is added or removed.  See the docs [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/).

Properties are computed lazily (while observers are not), so adding `itemsWithData` to your template is forcing `itemsWithData` to be computed.  If it's not called anywhere else it will not be computed.

Also note that Ember [overrides the native array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html). So if you have `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES` or `Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES.Array` set to `false` observing an array may not work.

Comment: Thx a lot...But could u explain the .[] and .@each with some examples to get more clarity on the usage..

Comment: Is that more helpful?

Comment: So if I understand correctly...say I have itemsWithData: [
 obj1: {
  prop1: '1',
  prop2: '2'
 },
 obj2: {}
]

In this case, if I just say property('itemsWithData'), it will get triggered even if the value of obj1.prop1 changes, but if I say property('itemsWithData.[]'), it will not triggered if say obj1.prop1 changes to '2', but will trigger only if obj1 or obj2 get removed or a new obj3 gets added. Pls let me know if my understanding is correct

Comment: `property('itemsWithData')` will not trigger unless `itemsWithData` changes from `null` to an array or vice versa.  `property('itemsWithData.[]')` will trigger if you add or remove items from the array (as you say), but not if the properties on the items change.  if you want to observe `prop1` on every object it is `property('itemsWithData.@each.prop1`).  If you're seeing issues note that there is a [bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475) in Ember 2.x related to this.